# Nativescript Cli 6.0 running the ios app to multiple devices

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing android and ios applications using a native script-angular framework. A couple of days back I upgraded from native script 5.3.4 to native script 6.x. After upgrading, I used a tns-migrate command to migrate my project. I have multiple iPhone devices for testing the app. When I was building the app with a single device via USB cable the app should be run on connected device but the app is running in other devices too. Why does this issue occur? I want to run my application only to the connected device but the nativescript6.0 runs the app in other iPhone devices too. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which commands you are using to run? Are other devices connected to same network?

Comment: I am using tns run ios command to run the app. Yes, other devices are connected the same network.

Comment: Run `tns devices` and see which device is yours, then pass the device parameter `--device [id|index]` in run command.

Comment: i have already run the command  using the device id but the error shows like "application id not found".

Comment: Application id? Can you post the complete error log when you use device id

Comment: Invalid application id: undefined. All available application ids are: 
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]

Comment: Is your application id same as one you have configured in Apple? It works if you have only one device connected?

Comment: Yes i have configured with the application id with apple.i will check and let you know it's working if single device connected.